# recaptcha is not verifying -rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

Previously I was able to delete the user using an admin account, after I've added the recaptcha gem I was unable to do so.
I've tried the same method using recaptcha in adding a post and it works, but it doesn't work on delete.

*users_controller.rb*

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if verify_recaptcha(model: @user) && @user.destroy
    redirect_to @user
  else
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
end
```

*index.html.erb*

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <td> <%= link_to "Delete", admin_destroy_user_path(user), 
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                    :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>.  
  </td>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
 match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
```

Can you guys please help me to identify what seems to be the problem? Based on my understanding i think there's something wrong with the

```
if verify_recaptcha
```

because when i did something like `!if verify_recaptcha && @user.destroy` the user will be deleted and will show error message:  reCAPTCHA verification failed, please try again. So i assume something is wrong with verifying the captcha

Comment: Please add error which you getting when you delete user. it should not be  `redirect_to @user` and `@user.destroy` should be inside if condition

Comment: @Vishal it doesn't show any error tho, I've tried adding the `@user.destory` inside if condition it still doesn't work

Comment: May be you are getting false in this condition`verify_recaptcha(model: @user) ` , try to put  `@user.destroy` above this condition , and check if user destroy

Comment: i think should be getting false condition, if i put `@user.destroy` on top of verify_recaptcha, it will delete the user even if i didnt tick the captcha box

Comment: yes than issue is in `verify_recaptcha(model: @user)` may be you don't code is correctly. i did this in my previous project may be you need to do something like this `verify_recaptcha(model: @user, response: captcha_response)`

Comment: `captcha_response is params[:user][:captcha]`, you should get captcha in params

Comment: u mean `response: params[:user][:captcha]`?

Comment: yes. i mean that

Comment: cant tho leads to lots of error

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `recaptcha`, but it seems like that's not the problem. Change `@user.destroy` to `@user.destroy!`. That way, it will raise an error when it doesn't delete instead of just returning `false`. Then you can see why it isn't deleting.

Comment: @RyanK tried that, it doesn't show any error tho

Comment: when i do something like 
`if verify_recaptcha` then below it `@user.destroy` it will show an error message reCAPTCHA verification failed, please try again

Comment: or if i do `!if verify_recaptcha(model: @user) && @user.destroy` `redirect..` `else` `redirect..` the user will be deleted. So i guess something is not right at `! if verify_recaptcha(model: @user)`